# Выделение в TextBox с правой стороны

Tags: c#, wpf

Текстовое поле с шириной Auto не имеет отступов внутри себя, границы текстового поля подпирают текст, выделить его с правого края крайне неудобно. Если задать Padding, то и курсор при наведении на получившийся отступ будет Arrow, и при клике с дальнейшем движении мыши влево выделения не произойдет. Таких проблем не возникает, если немного увеличить ширину текстового поля. Но нельзя - предполагается ввод текста.

В VS в редактируемых строках элементов интерфейса есть отступ.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В Word также отступы с трех сторон  позволяют выделять текст при клике за границами текстовых символов (только слева поле имеет другие свойства).
Что я сделал:

```
<Canvas Height="{Binding ElementName=tbEdit, Path=ActualHeight}">
     <TextBox Name="tbEdit" Text="MainWindow.xaml"
              Padding="0,0,20,0"
              MouseEnter="TextBox_MouseEnter"
              PreviewMouseDown="TextBox_MouseDown"
              TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"
              >
     </TextBox>
</Canvas>
void TextBox_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var tbEdit = sender as TextBox;
        tbEdit.Cursor = Cursors.IBeam;
    }
    void TextBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var tbEdit = sender as TextBox;

        var widthTextBox = tbEdit.ActualWidth;
        tbEdit.Padding = new Thickness(0);
        tbEdit.MinWidth = widthTextBox;
    }
    private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tbEdit = sender as TextBox;

        double pad = 20.0;
        if (tbEdit.Padding.Right < pad)
        {
            tbEdit.MinWidth = 10;
            tbEdit.Padding = new Thickness(0, 0, pad, 0);
        }    
    }
```

Вопрос: можно ли сделать проще?

Comment: Возможно проще добавить небольшую невидимую кнопку справа к textBox при нажатии на которую выделять текст?

Comment: Да ну) В текстовых полях ведь не так. Хотелось бы, чтобы все было обыкновенно: захотел - выделил, не захотел, просто кликнул, переместив каретку в конец строки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Предлагаю использовать такой трюк - разместить в окне дополнительный `TextBlock` (ну или еще один `TextBox` - не принципиально важно, но, думаю, `TextBlock` будет немного быстрее работать), свойство `Text` второго элемента привязать к `Text` первого, а свойство `Width` первого привязать к `ActualWidth` второго, с помощью `Padding` во втором элементе теперь можно регулировать дополнительный отступ, после чего второй элемент можно скрыть:

```
<Canvas>
    <TextBox Name="box" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=block}"/>
    <TextBlock Name="block" Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=box}"
               Padding="0,0,20,0" Visibility="Hidden"/>
</Canvas>
```

обратите внимание, следует использовать именно `Hidden`, а не `Collapsed` иначе это не сработает.

Всё!

[image: Жили-были]

Если вам нужно такое поведение в нескольких местах - оформите эту конструкцию в виде отдельного контрола. Ну и не забудьте: если меняете размер шрифта - меняйте его у обоих элементов.

Comment: Спасибо! Только с гридом у меня некорректно работает: ширина  изменяется только при вводе, а при удалении части текста - ширина не меняется. С канвасом все четко.

Comment: @UggoFantozzi, да, можно обернуть текстбокс и текстблок в канвас и вынести отдельным контролом, главное если меняете размер шрифта - меняйте его в обоих контролах сразу